# Android Admob InterstitialAd Deprecated

Tags: android, admob, deprecated

After updating `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` to `19.7.0`
it says `InterstitialAd` & `RewardedVideoAd` & `UnifiedNativeAdView` deprecated.

can anyone help ?

Comment: I don't understand what is going on. Cause, one by one every material is deprecating. 
I had the issue with `File.Filecolumns.DATA` `DATA` is deprecated also. Now, I am seeing `InterstitialAd` and `RewardedViewAd` also. :(

Comment: And replacements in many cases are missing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

after a quick search, I found that we need to use

```
public abstract class InterstitialAd extends Object
```

instead of

```
public final class InterstitialAd extends Object
```

so you need to use:

```
com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd
```

instead of:

```
come.google.android.gms.ads
```

and this is how we interact with the new package:

```
public class AdManager 
{
    private var interstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null
    private var mRewardedVideoAd: RewardedAd? = null
    private var currentNativeAd: NativeAd? = null
    private var builder: AdLoader.Builder? = null



    init {
        RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(
            listOf(
                AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR,
                "CE88B9A1CB213EEEA19A2F7E54993908"
            )
        )
    }
    // Create a full screen content callback.
    val fullScreenContentCallback = object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
        override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(p0: AdError) {
            super.onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(p0)
        }

        override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
            super.onAdShowedFullScreenContent()
        }

        override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
            super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()
            interstitialAd = null
            mRewardedVideoAd = null
        }

    }

    fun createInterstitialAd(context: Context) {
     
            InterstitialAd.load(
                context,
                BuildConfig.ADMOB_AD_INTERSTITIAL_UNIT_ID,
                request.build(),
                object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                    override fun onAdLoaded(ad: InterstitialAd) {
                        interstitialAd = ad
                        interstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = fullScreenContentCallback
                    }

                })
        }
    }

    fun getFullScreenAd(): InterstitialAd? {
        return interstitialAd
    }

    fun getVideoAd(): RewardedAd? {
        return mRewardedVideoAd
    }

    fun loadRewardedVideoAd(context: Context) {
        if (!userManager.getCurrentUser().isPremium) {
            val request = AdRequest.Builder()
     

            RewardedAd.load(
                context,
                BuildConfig.ADMOB_AD_VIDEO_UNIT_ID,
                AdRequest.Builder().build(),
                object : RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                    override fun onAdLoaded(ad: RewardedAd) {
                        super.onAdLoaded(ad)
                        mRewardedVideoAd = ad;
                        mRewardedVideoAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = fullScreenContentCallback;
                    }
                    override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: LoadAdError) {
                        super.onAdFailedToLoad(p0)

                    }
                })
        }
   

    fun loadNativeAd(context: Activity,adFrame:FrameLayout) {
      
            builder = AdLoader.Builder(context, BuildConfig.ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID_DIALOG_NATIVE)
            builder?.forNativeAd { unifiedNativeAd: NativeAd ->
                val adView: View =
                    context.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_unified, null)
                val ad = adView as NativeAdView
                populateUnifiedNativeAdView(unifiedNativeAd, ad)
                adFrame.removeAllViews()
                adFrame.addView(ad)
            }
            val adLoader = builder?.withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(i: LoadAdError) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(i)
                    Log.e("NativeAdFailed", i.toString() + "")
                }
            })?.build()
            val builder = AdManagerAdRequest.Builder()
            adLoader?.loadAd(builder.build())
        }
    }


    private fun populateUnifiedNativeAdView(
        nativeAd: NativeAd,
        adView: NativeAdView
    ) {
        // You must call destroy on old ads when you are done with them,
        // otherwise you will have a memory leak.
        if (currentNativeAd != null) currentNativeAd?.destroy()
        currentNativeAd = nativeAd

        // Set the media view.
        adView.mediaView = adView.findViewById<View>(R.id.ad_media) as com.google.android.gms.ads.nativead.MediaView

        // Set other ad assets.
        adView.headlineView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_headline)
        adView.bodyView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_body)
        adView.callToActionView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_call_to_action)
        adView.iconView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_app_icon)
        adView.priceView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_price)
        adView.starRatingView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_stars)
        adView.storeView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_store)
        adView.advertiserView = adView.findViewById(R.id.ad_advertiser)

        // The headline and media content are guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd.
        (adView.headlineView as TextView).text = nativeAd.headline
        nativeAd.mediaContent?.let {
            adView.mediaView?.setMediaContent(it)

        }

        // These assets aren't guaranteed to be in every UnifiedNativeAd, so it's important to
        // check before trying to display them.
        if (nativeAd.body == null) {
            adView.bodyView?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            adView.bodyView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            (adView.bodyView as TextView).text = nativeAd.body
        }
        if (nativeAd.callToAction == null) {
            adView.callToActionView?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            adView.callToActionView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            (adView.callToActionView as TextView).text = nativeAd.callToAction
        }
        if (nativeAd.icon == null) {
            adView.iconView?.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            (adView.iconView as ImageView).setImageDrawable(
                nativeAd.icon?.drawable
            )
            adView.iconView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
        if (nativeAd.price == null) {
            adView.priceView?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            adView.priceView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            (adView.priceView as TextView).text = nativeAd.price
        }
        if (nativeAd.store == null) {
            adView.storeView?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            adView.storeView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            (adView.storeView as TextView).text = nativeAd.store
        }
        if (nativeAd.starRating == null) {
            adView.starRatingView?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            nativeAd.starRating?.toDouble()?.let {
                (adView.starRatingView as RatingBar).rating = it.toFloat()
                adView.starRatingView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }


        }
        if (nativeAd.advertiser == null) {
            adView.advertiserView?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        } else {
            (adView.advertiserView as TextView).text = nativeAd.advertiser
            adView.advertiserView?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        // This method tells the Google Mobile Ads SDK that you have finished populating your
        // native ad view with this native ad.
        adView.setNativeAd(nativeAd)
    }
}
```

Comment: oh. the link is dead

Answer (score 6):

> There are many breaking changes coming in version 20.0.0. Version
> 19.7.0 introduced many new APIs, and deprecated or renamed many classes in preparation for version 20.0.0.

This code explains how to integrate interstitial ads in v 19.7.0

```kotlin
class Web : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web)

        // load ad
        loadAd();

        toNextLevel()
    }

    // load ad
    private fun loadAd() {
        InterstitialAd.load(
            this@Web,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712",
            AdRequest.Builder().build(),
            object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
                    // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                    // an ad is loaded.
                    mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
                    mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback =
                        object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
                            override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()
                                mInterstitialAd = null

                                //// perform your code that you wants to do after ad dismissed or closed
                            }

                            override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError) {
                                super.onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError)
                                mInterstitialAd = null

                                /// perform your action here when ad will not load
                            }

                            override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                super.onAdShowedFullScreenContent()
                                this@Web.mInterstitialAd = null
                            }
                        }
                }

                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError: LoadAdError) {
                    // Handle the error
                    mInterstitialAd = null
                }
            })
    }

    private fun toNextLevel() {
        // Show the interstitial if it is ready. Otherwise, proceed to the next level
        // without ever showing it
        if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
            mInterstitialAd?.show(this@Web)
        } else {
            nextLevel()

            // in case you want to load a new ad
            requestNewInterstitial()
        }
    }

    private fun nextLevel() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    private fun requestNewInterstitial() {
        if (mInterstitialAd == null) {
            loadAd()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

use com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd

instead of

come.google.android.gms.ads

Answer (score 4):

when you upgrade the admob sdk to

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:19.7.0'
```

you will found the old sdk method deprecated like InterstitialAD

Its Simple here just follow my way to load your interstitial and remove deprecation here its my sample code for better ad request load your add in the On start in your activity if you have any query kindly let me know below in comments copy paste the below code:

```
   public static  AdRequest adRequest;
public static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
public void InterstitialAdmob() {
    InterstitialAd.load(MainActivity.this,getString(R.string.Interstitial), adRequest, new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
            // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
            // an ad is loaded.
            mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
            mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback(){

                @Override
                public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    super.onAdDismissedFullScreenContent();
                    mInterstitialAd=null;

                    //// perform your code that you wants todo after ad dismissed or closed


                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdError adError) {
                    super.onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError);
                    mInterstitialAd = null;

                    /// perform your action here when ad will not load
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    super.onAdShowedFullScreenContent();
                    mInterstitialAd = null;

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
            // Handle the error
            mInterstitialAd = null;
            

        }

    });

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    measyrating.onStart();
    adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    InterstitialAdmob();

}
```

Now show your ads simply on backpressed or button click

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mInterstitialAd!=null){
        mInterstitialAd.show(MainActivity.this);
    }
    else{

        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            if (mBottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId() == R.id.navigation_doc)
            {
                super.onBackPressed();

            }
            else

            {

                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_doc);
            }
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        if (this.drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {

            this.drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        }


        if (itempositionselected==0){

            loadFragment(new DocxFileFragment());

        }
        else {


        }

        if (!searchView.isIconified()) {

            searchView.setIconified(true);

        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }


}
```

Comment: I don't understand your code. I made a separate class as AdManager. Help me from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66294199/how-to-solve-interstitial-ads-is-deprecated

Comment: is it now that we cannot check whether a user has clicked or has not clicked the ad? (If I don't use analytic, I may need to count number of indecent click)

Comment: will it show the Ads? I have added this codes and published, will let you know shows the Ads or not, but are sure about the ads will show or not? would be mental satisfaction. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Google Mobile Ads SDK version 20.0.0 is planned for early 2021 and comes with a few major changes, as well as several straightforward API renames and removal of deprecated APIs.
You can check more details on [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/migration) link.
Use NativeAdView instead of UnifiedNativeAdView and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Following page has example and details for newer version of interstitial ad

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

Below is a full working example based on above i am using with current version`com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.2.0`:

```
    public class BriefDisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    InterstitialAd briefInterstitialAd;


    AdRequest adRequest_I = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    InterstitialAd.load(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712", adRequest_I,
            new InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull InterstitialAd interstitialAd) {
                    // The mInterstitialAd reference will be null until
                    // an ad is loaded.
                    BriefDisplayActivity.this.briefInterstitialAd = interstitialAd;
                    Log.i(TAG, "onAdLoaded");
                    briefInterstitialAd.show(BriefDisplayActivity.this);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                    // Handle the error
                    Log.i(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                    BriefDisplayActivity.this.briefInterstitialAd = null;
                }
            });
            
    }
```